# export mixed NLA editor data

Tags: animation, export, nla-editor

Is it possible to convert/export the mixed NLA tracks into a single animation?
For example if I manipulate motion capture data, to give the manipulated motion data out as a single animation?

Comment: you can bake several NLA strips and it will give you one unique action, but there will be one keyframe per frame

Comment: since motion capture data usuallly has a keyframe per frame, thats not a problem. thank you very much! do you have a good tutorial on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work this way: Select the armature in *Object* mode, in the NLA select the different strips that you want to merge, in the *3D view > Object > Animation*, click on *Bake*, in the pop-up panel disable *Only Selected Bones* (if you want to bake all the bones), choose *Bake Data > Pose* instead of *Object*, click on *OK*. A new action should be created that you can push down into the NLA.

Comment: Great, thank you!!